# Create a multidimensional hashwith an adding value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a hash that can add value to itself using +=1

```
@hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(0) }
@hash[string1][string2] += 1
```

This returns a hash that looks like:

```
@hash = {string1 => {string2 => 1 }}
```

And that integer value increments by one every time that the same string values are iterated over.

Now I need to add another value to the hash so it looks like this...

```
@hash = {string1 => {string2 => {string3 => 1}}}
```

And have that number increment the same way.

Unfortunately this code:

```
@hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(0)}
@hash[string1][string2][string3] += 1
```

Returns an error saying "Can't convert string to integer." I have a feeling it's because there's an added element, and I have Hash.new(0), so it's expecting an integer in the spot where I have a string.  Is that correct?

How would I set up this hash so that it can handle an extra dimension and still do the += 1 at the end so the value increments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> h=Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=Hash.new(0)}}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h[:a][:b][:c]+=1
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> h
=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>1}}}
```

Comment: This most directly answers my problem, needing three keys and +=1 for the value.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you can't. You can either have en empty key default to a new hash, or have
the it default to `0`, so you'll have to pick what's more important and handle the other case with your own class behavior.

In your first example, are you starting with `string2 => 1` and replacing that with `string2 => { string3 => 1 }`, or are those two seperate examples?

This hash will let you look up and set values at an arbitrary depth without requiring them to exist first:

```
h = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }
h[1][2][3] = 4  #=> {1=>{2=>{3=>4}}}
```

**Update**

Here's an example of how a class wrapper might work (quick and dirty, and untested):

```
require 'forwardable'
class AutoHash
  extend Forwardable
  attr_reader :data

  def_delegators :@data, :[], :[]=

  def initialize
    @data = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }
  end

  def increment(*keys, value)
    current_hash = data
    keys[0..-2].each do |key|
      current_hash = current_hash[key]
    end
    current_hash[keys[-1]] = 0 unless current_hash.has_key?(keys[-1])
    current_hash[keys[-1]] += value
  end
end

a = AutoHash.new
a.increment(:string1, :string2, :string3, 2)
a.increment(:string1, :string2, :string3, 5)
a.increment(:string1, :string4, 10)

a.data # => {:string1=>{:string2=>{:string3=>7}, :string4=>10}}
```

Comment: A great idea!  I appreciate the help.  Is it totally necessary?  Answer 2 works as well, and even simpler than that was the answer that got deleted...

@hash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }}

Comment: No it's probably not necessary, but I was operating with the assumption that you needed hashes nested to arbitrary depths. If it only ever needs to be exactly three keys deep, use the simpler version.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized that you want to add arbitrarily many keys, not just exactly three. I put the answer back.

Comment: Ok great, thanks guys.  If I need to go further than three, I'll take a look at answer 1 again.

Comment: Yep, I appreciate the feedback, OMG.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can overload that.  But you could derive another:

```
@hash2=Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = @hash }
```

that should let you use @hash for 2 dimensions and @hash2 for 3 dimensions

If you need variable length, and a method call is acceptable, you could use something like

```
def deephash (*keys)
  return 0 if keys.length == 0
  key = keys.shift
  { key => deephash(*keys) }
end

n=deephash("a","b","c","d")
=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>0}}}}

n["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"] += 1
=> 1

n
=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>1}}}}
```